# jquery $.each() for objects

Tags: jquery, each

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var data = { "programs": [ { "name":"zonealarm", "price":"500" }, { "name":"kaspersky", "price":"200" } ] };
        $.each(data.programs[0], function(key,val) {
            alert(key+val);
        });
    });
</script>
```

This code retrieves the first data. `name:zonealarm` and `price:500`.

**How can I retrieve all the data in the object?**

I tried `$.each(data.programs, function(key,val)` but it didn't work.

Should I put it in a loop?

Answer (score 147, accepted):

`$.each()` works for objects and arrays both:

```
var data = { "programs": [ { "name":"zonealarm", "price":"500" }, { "name":"kaspersky", "price":"200" } ] };

$.each(data.programs, function (i) {
    $.each(data.programs[i], function (key, val) {
        alert(key + val);
    });
});
```

...and since you will get the current array element as second argument:

```
$.each(data.programs, function (i, currProgram) {
    $.each(currProgram, function (key, val) {
        alert(key + val);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 15):

You are indeed passing the first data item to the each function.

Pass data.programs to the each function instead.
Change the code to as below:

```
<script>     
    $(document).ready(function() {         
        var data = { "programs": [ { "name":"zonealarm", "price":"500" }, { "name":"kaspersky", "price":"200" } ] };         
        $.each(data.programs, function(key,val) {             
            alert(key+val);         
        });     
    }); 
</script>
```

Comment: but then i don't get exact values just the index of the each object?

Comment: Because you're getting the whole Object here.
To get exact values/extract values from Object : 

console.log(key +" "+ val.name + " " + val.price);

Answer (score 9):

Basically you need to do two loops here. The one you are doing already is iterating each element in the 0th array element.

You have programs: [ {...}, {...} ]
so programs[0] is { "name":"zonealarm", "price":"500" }
So your loop is just going over that.

You could do an outer loop over the array

```
$.each(data.programs, function(index) {

    // then loop over the object elements
    $.each(data.programs[index], function(key, value) {
        console.log(key + ": " + value);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

#### Insert data in  "INId" div...

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
        var data = { "programs": [ { "name":"zonealarm", "price":"500" }, { "name":"kaspersky", "price":"200" } ] };
        $.each(data.programs, function(key,val) {
            // console.log(val);
            $('#InId').append("Name: " +val.name+" & Price: "+val.price+"<br/>");
        });
    });
```

$(document).ready(function() {
var data = { "programs": [ { "name":"zonealarm", "price":"500" }, { "name":"kaspersky", "price":"200" } ] };
$.each(data.programs, function(key,val) {
// console.log(val);
$('#InId').append("Name: " +val.name+" & Price: "+val.price+"
");
});
});

Answer (score 2):

```
var arType = [];
$.each($("input[name='archiveType[]']:checked"), function() {
   arType.push($(this).val());
});
arType = arType.join(",");
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.