# Get value from object within JQuery each function

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I have an Object that contains an associative array

[image]

The value stored in the array is an Object

Within the each function, I want to access one of the values in the value object (`responseText`)

[image]

My code is as follows

```
 var apiNameArray = getDataSourceApiNames();
        var apiResults = {};
        var deferred;

        for (let i = 0; i < apiNameArray.length; i++) {
            var apiName = apiNameArray[i];
            console.log("apiName = " + apiName);
            deferred = $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: api_URL + "memberdetails/" + memberNumber,
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json"
                }
            );
            apiResults[apiName] = deferred;
        }

        $.when.apply($, apiResults).then(function () {
            console.log(apiResults);
            $.each(apiResults, function (key, value) {
                console.log(key);
                console.log(value);
                console.log(value.responseText);
           });
        });
```

For some reason, `value.responseText` is returning undefined. How am I suppose to be accessing this value/property? I have tried `value["responseText"]`, `apiResults[key].responseText` all with no success

Comment: Can you show the ajax request code too? It looks like the value you are after is out of scope.

Comment: use `JSON.parse()` method.

Comment: If the first screenshot is the OP of the `console.log(apiResults);` then you can simply access the responseText like `apiResults[0]['responseText']`. You can replace the `0` with a loop index.

Comment: Post amended to show AJAX call

Comment: @swetanshkumar - it is already an object

Comment: Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6208079/3008050) to understand how `each` works for array and object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the `apiResults` is a object you can loop though the keys and use `apiResults[key].responseText` to access the value.

`$.when.apply($, apiResults).then(function () {
      $.each(apiResults, function (key, value) {
       console.log(apiResults[key].responseText);
      });
 });`

or

`$.when.apply($, apiResults).then(function () {
   Object.keys('apiResults').forEach(function(item, index){
     console.log(apiResults[item].responseText)
   })
});`

Here `Object.keys` will return an array of all the keys in an object.

Comment: That still returns undefined for apiResults[key].responseText

Comment: @mike can you please create a fiddle of your code. As per my understanding the above code should work.

Comment: How do I mimic the AJAX response in jsfiddle?

Comment: Save the response in a JS variable and run the loop.

Comment: I am going to undo the downvote and mark as the answer - it was because my promise was not waiting for the API success to complete before populating the array. So when I looped through the values, it was empty (and therefore undefined)